# How to save the json array data in database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

does anyone know how to store the data in this format **["123"]** in PHPMyAdmin?

Now the data I store into the database is only the value which is **123**. I want to store the data like this **["123"]**. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
Company::create([
   'companyID' =>  $people->people_id,
]);
```

Comment: You can use the json type for the column. But in my opinion, you should not save multiple ids in one column, because that would make queries with relationships a lot harder.

Comment: @GertB. thank you for your reply, how to put in json type?

Comment: I agree with Gert, and if you want to have multiple references it's wise to let the orm handle it instead of manually encoding your data to json.

Comment: @JervenClark thank you for your reply. I am new to laravel.  Let the orm handle it means like create the relationship between different table right?

Comment: @dipgirl indeed thats what it means. Read the Laravel docs on Eloquent relationships, that would be the best option.

Comment: Try json_encode($data); When you want to fetch, you json_decode() the field

Comment: @NobleEugene thank you for your reply. I have tried add json_encode() but the data still store only value

Answer (score 0):

To store data the way you want to, you need to change the datatype for the column of the table to json. It can be done in your migration file like:

`$table->json('column_name');`

After migrating your table you have to add casting for the specific column in your model file. It can be done as:

```
protected $casts = [
   'column_name' => 'array',
];
```

Once you have done this, you can then store data as json in your database.

You can find more information about casting at [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) here.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 0):

You can save text data in mysql table column. For this you should change your column type to text and follow the following code as reference.

You will have to change your array to json data and pass variable to create method as value. Remember that, for storing string value you will have to wrap value with quotations.

```
$data = json_encode([
    123, "124", 134.4, "450"
]);

Company::create([

    'companyID' => $data

]);
```

Comment: If you would use a json column, it's better to use casts in Laravel instead of manually encoding.